# Django render function gives error dict expected at most 1 arguments, got 3

Tags: python, django

```
def home(request):
    """Renders the home page."""
    assert isinstance(request, HttpRequest)

    return render(
        request,
        'app/index.html',
        context = RequestContext(request,                                 
        {
            'title':'Home Page'            
        })
    )
```

I am getting an error at dictionary object.

dict expected at most 1 arguments, got 3

Comment: maybe that can help: you don't need to use `RequestContext`, you can just pass the extra context as a dictionnary

Comment: What do I need to do in my code

Comment: you would need to replace `context = RequestContext(...)` with `context={'title':'Home Page'}`.
Also it helps to post the stacktrace.

Comment: wow that worked!!! Thanks

Comment: Why are you asserting on the request? What else could it be? Why would you want to do that in production code?

Comment: oh no...the code is the shell of Django web project.
So just ignore that line

Answer (score 0):

As sly_Chandan said: don't use

```
def home(request):
    return render(
        request,
        'app/index.html',
        {
            'title': 'Home Page'
        }
    )
```

With newer Django it's a good idea to follow modern patterns even for small applications, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/class-based-views/base/#templateview:

```
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView

def HomePageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'app/index.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(HomePageView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['title'] = 'Home Page'
        return context
```

And then in the `urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', HomePageView.as_view(), name='home'),
]
```